# link iBeacon URL to Physical Web from Google Dashboard

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I want to use Physical Web for broadcasting my URL from the beacon instead of Nearby notification feature.
Please suggest steps for the same.

Comment: It's certainly easy to set up Physical Web broadcasting.   But what do you want to do on the receiving side that is different than what Nearby does?  Are you using a custom app?  Are you targeting Android, iOS or both?

Comment: On the receiving side on Android and iOS, I want to show the user wth the URL to move to.
Also I want to know, how could I configure the URL remotely to any beacon from the Google Beacon Dashboard

Comment: The Google Beacon Dashboard does not allow you to change the url broadcasted by Physical Web beacons.  You would need to configure each beacon with the url using tools provided by the manufacturer.